# Docker Container publish error on Azure

Tags: azure, docker

I have created a docker image from ASP.NET 4.5 version on Windows 10 using the base image **microsoft/windowsservercore**. I then deployed my changes to the image using CLI.

I then pushed my image to Azure Container Registry. Now when I try to create a Container on Azure using the above image I get the below error:

**"The OS version of image xxxx.azurecr.io/xxximage:latest" is not supported. (Code:OsVersionNotSupported)**

Any help is much appreciated as I have spent quite a lot of time investigating this.

Comment: Are you try to create a container on Azure VM? Or Azure container service?

Comment: Hi, I am using Azure Container Instance. Do I need to create a VM first?

Comment: Are you create Azure container instance via Azure portal in Azure container registry, select Repositories and `run instance`? that not work for you?

Comment: yes this is what I am doing and so I get this error

Comment: @John Were you able to solve this? I'm getting the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Only Windows LTS version of containers are supported at the moment for ACI. You can find some clue here: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/8586

e.g. you can use **microsoft/aspnet:4.6.2-windowsservercore-ltsc2016** image which can then be pushed and deployed in Azure.